# How to access a Variable or list or dictionary inside a method of a class, outside the class?

Tags: python, class, methods

```
class test:

    def __init__(self):

        print('inside the code')

    def add(self,x,y):

        a=x+y

    def list_test(self):

        ar=[]
        ar.append(1)
        ar.append(2)


    def dict_test(self):
        dict_t={1:2,2:3}

cl=test()
```

How do access `a`, `ar` and `dict_t` outside the class? I want to print `a` and `ar` here. Thank You.

Comment: But your methods don't really do anything? `a`, `ar` and `dict_t` are all local variables inside those methods, at least assign them in `self` no?

Comment: Actually I was writing another code and I faced this problem there, i just wrote this test code to  show the problem i was facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ar = []
        self.dict_t = {}
        self.a = 0
        print('inside the code')

    def add(self, x, y):
        self.a = x+y

    def list_test(self):
        self.ar.append(1)
        self.ar.append(2)

    def dict_test(self):
        self.dict_t = {1: 2, 2: 3}


t = test()
t.list_test()
print(t.ar)
t.add()
print(t.a)
```

Note:

Define your variables in the initiate function.
Then you can access them through:

```
class_name.var_name
```

Comment: Ok, that did it, Thanks a lot .